# abort jquery pos after get message saying already exist from database jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how do i abort the jquery process after i get the message saying data already exist on database? it is because i need to check the id, if not exist then insert to database using  $.post("process.php"), is it even possible?

```
$.post("checkdata.php", {        //check from database if id already exist
id1: id                          //data to be check from database
}, function(data) {
if (data == 'CUSTOMER ID ALREADY EXIST!') { // if return this terminated the process
$("#output").html("CUSTOMER ID ALREADY EXIST!"); //showing error to client
$("form")[0].reset();            //reset the form
e.abort();                       //aborting the process
}

if (code == '' || (code.length) < 8) {
$("#output").html("CUSTOMER CODE SHOULD HAVE ATLEAST 8 CHARACTER");
$("#code").addClass('error');
$("#code").focus();
}

$.post("process.php", {
id1: id,
code1: code
}, function(data) {
if (data == 'Information added successfully!') {
$("#output").html("Information added successfully!");
$("form")[0].reset();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is restructure your code so that your check in the browser happens first (validating the form). After that, if the form is valid, you can make your request to the server (`checkdata.php`). Once you get your response you can decide if you are going to continue to make another request to the server (`process.php`).

```
// Validate the form
if (code == '' || (code.length) < 8) {
  $("#output").html("CUSTOMER CODE SHOULD HAVE ATLEAST 8 CHARACTER");
  $("#code").addClass('error');
  $("#code").focus();
}
else {
  // The form is valid

  $.post("checkdata.php", {
    id1: id
  }, function(data) {

    if (data == 'CUSTOMER ID ALREADY EXIST!') {
      $("#output").html("CUSTOMER ID ALREADY EXIST!");
      $("form")[0].reset();
      return; // Don't continue with the following lines;
    }

    $.post("process.php", {
      id1: id,
      code1: code
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == 'Information added successfully!') {
        $("#output").html("Information added successfully!");
        $("form")[0].reset();
      }
    });

  });

}
```

I will note you probably don't need to make two requests to the server. Just send one request to `process.php` and before process begins it's processing it does some validating, such as checking if the customer exists. If the customer does exist then you can send a response indicating this.

```
// Client.js
if (code == '' || (code.length) < 8) {
  $("#output").html("CUSTOMER CODE SHOULD HAVE ATLEAST 8 CHARACTER");
  $("#code").addClass('error');
  $("#code").focus();
}
else {

  // The form is valid

  $.post("process.php", {
    id1: id,
    code1: code
  }, function(data) {
    if (data == 'duplicate customer') {
      $("#output").html("This is a duplicate customer");
      $("form")[0].reset();
    }
    else if (data = 'successful') {
      $("#output").html("Customer successfully added");
      $("form")[0].reset();
    }
    else {
      $("#output").html("Unknown error");
      // $("form")[0].reset();
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: what i want is basicly like this, check id if duplicate from server side -> pass all the text input(JS) -> add data to server, i dont want they(customer) pass all the client side but when reach the server side, their request is rejected because id is duplicated, the js i put here was only for 2 textbox to make it short but the real one having more than 10

Comment: to let you know, the id also come from textbox and all textbox is required, and from the second code you type, you let the customer pass all the client side need then checking if duplicate, after that insert to database, let say its fail when inserting that time after customer has pass all the 10+ textbox(JS), he/she might run away

Comment: Since this is an ajax request, you can make a request to the server as soon as the id field looses focus. For the user, they might tab away or click on another field. Then, by the time they are finishing filling out the second field you can display a message saying the id is a duplicate. That way, it doesn't break the users flow until it has to.